# Ayuda con un Calendario en Linea de Codigo

Tags: java

Pues se supone que mi código debería imprimir en algunos meses 31 días según una de mis condiciones pero no lo hace de hecho imprime un día menos en todos los meses.

Si alguien puede ayudarme y chequear mi código seria de gran ayuda, se que hay cosas que podrían estar simplificadas pero solo estoy aprendiendo.

Gracias de ante mano

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CalFinal{ 
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Insert Year:");
        int year =sc.nextInt();

        if (year <= 0){

            System.out.println( year + " Is an invalid Year");
        }



        for (int mo = 1 ; mo <= 12 ; mo++){
            int days = daysOfMonth(year, mo);
            int countDays = 0;
            if (mo == 1 ){
                System.out.println("       January");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }


                }

                System.out.println() ;

            }else if (mo == 2 ){
                System.out.println("       February");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println() ;

            }else if (mo == 3 ){
                System.out.println("         March");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println() ;

            }else if (mo == 4 ){
                System.out.println("         April");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println() ;

            }else if (mo == 5 ){
                System.out.println("         May");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println() ;

            }else if (mo == 6 ){
                System.out.println("          June");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println() ;

            }else if (mo == 7 ){
                System.out.println("          July");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println() ;

            }else if (mo == 8 ){
                System.out.println("         August");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println() ;

            }else if (mo == 9 ){
                System.out.println("         September");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println() ;

            }else if (mo == 10 ){
                System.out.println("          October");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println() ;

            }else if (mo == 11){
                System.out.println("         November");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println() ;

            }else{
                System.out.println("          December");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");
                for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(""+dy +  "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println() ;

            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year){

        if ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0 ) || (year % 400 == 0)){
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static int daysOfMonth (int year, int month){
        if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12){
            return 31;
        }else if(month  == 2){
            if(isLeapYear(year)){
                return 29;
            }else{
                return 28;
            }
        }else{
            return 30;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debido a la condición del ciclo `for` (`dy < days`), sólo imprimes 30 para los meses con 31 y 29 para los meses con 30, etc. Debería ser **`dy <= days`**.

Necesitas cambiar en cada uno de los ciclos `for` de:

```
for (int dy = 1; dy < days; dy++){
```

a:

```
for (int dy = 1; dy <= days; dy++){
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Paul al final pues logre dar con el error, ahora tengo otro problema tratando de aplicar la formula de zeller para q las fechas concorden con los dias

Answer (score 0):

Pues aqui esta el codigo con la formula de Zeller al final la cosa es q me esta poniendo la fecha en el dia correcto

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CalFinal{ 
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Insert Year:");
        int year =sc.nextInt();

        if (year <= 0){

            System.out.println( year + " Is an invalid Year");
        }



        for (int mo = 1 ; mo <= 12 ; mo++){
            int days = daysOfMonth(year, mo);
            int rD = rightDay(year, mo);
            int countDays = 0;


            if (mo == 1 ){
                System.out.println("       January");
                System.out.println("Su\tMo\tTu\tWe\tTh\tFr\tSa");

                for (int d = 0; d < rD ; d++){

                System.out.print("\t");
                }   


                for (int dy = 1; dy <= days; dy++){
                    System.out.print(dy + "\t") ;
                    countDays ++;
                    if (countDays == 7){
                        System.out.println() ;
                        countDays = 0;
                    }


                }

                //System.out.println() ;

        }


private static int rightDay(int year, int month){
        int a = (14 - month) / 12;
        int y = year - a ;
        int m = month + 12 * a - 2;
        int day = 1, d;

        d = (day + y + y / 4 - y/ 100 + y / 400 + (31 * m ) / 12) %7;

        return(d);


    }
```